# C Programming bit representation

Tags: c, binary, permutation, bit, indicator

For example, I have 3 counters (which I essentially want to represent as truth values (counter > 0 true; false otherwise). This leads to 2^3 = 8 permutations for my truth values as shown:

000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111

Then each permutation maps to a state. How do I convert these counters to a binary representation at the bit level, and then how would I use the binary representation in a switch structure to map to a state? (ex. 001 maps to "contains x" and 010 maps to "contains y", and 011 would map to "contains x and y". Will this all be portable to other operating systems as well?

Comment: Is this for an embedded system or something? Otherwise, you might be better off (i.e. have easier to understand/maintain code) if you stick with byte values, rather than twiddling bits for something like this.

Comment: yes... I basically want to use the least amount of memory possible. So out of my three counters (x, y, z) suppose, x and z are > 0 (true). this means I would like to have 3 bits to represent 101. Then this could easily be checked against a switch statement

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility is to define constants with the value for each bit corresponding to each counter:

```
#define CTR1_BIT 0x01
#define CTR2_BIT 0x02
#define CTR3_BIT 0x04
```

Then based on the counter values (zero or non-zero) set the bits.  The `|` operator performs a bitwise logical OR operation (see [this for more information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)).  If `ctr1` is nonzero, it just sets the lowest order bit in the variable `state`.  If `ctr2` is nonzero, it sets the second bit in `state` to a 1 and leaves other bits unchanged.  etc.

```
   int state = 0;

   if ( ctr1 )
      state |= CTR1_BIT;
   if ( ctr2 )
      state |= CTR2_BIT;
   if ( ctr3 )
      state |= CTR3_BIT;
```

Then switch on the possible state values:

```
   switch ( state )
      {
      case 0x00:
         printf( "state 0\n" );
         break;
      case 0x01:
         printf( "state 1\n" );
         break;
      case 0x02:

         ...

      case 0x07:
         printf( "state 7\n" );
         break;
      default:
         printf( "Invalid state\n" );
         assert(0);
      }
```

Comment: Good idea with the hexadecimal! I am new to C, so I have 2 questions from this. 1) What can I use besides an int to use less bytes? I know a char is 1 byte. 2) How many bytes are required for Hex?

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus:  Since you are representing just the 7 states, a `char` would work as well (single byte).  If you are in a memory constrained environment, that might make sense.  The hex values are just constants; just a different style of integer representation.  It seemed more readable for this situation.  But since the values are all <=7, the hex versus decimal representation would be the same.  And, yes, it should be portable in all situations.

Comment: Could you explain the bitwise or assignment? I dont quite understand how that works. Say we have ctr1 and ctr2 true. could you walk me through the evaluation process? such as: bits = bits | 0x1  thus bits is now 1, bits = bits | 0x2 bits is now ??

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: I added more descriptive text that hopefully explains it.  Basically the use of bitwise OR operator with the chosen constant values (0x01, 0x02, 0x04 ... powers of 2), allow a specific single bit to be set to 1 (if it is not already one).

Comment: thanks man, I appreciate it a lot. It is quite strange but really cool getting down to the bit level with programming!